# JavaScript custom library css function not working

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I recently made a custom framework for JavaScript, but my '.css()' function is not working as an object notation, here is a part of my code:

```
const aps = function(selector) {
  if (!(this instanceof aps)) {
    return new aps(selector);
  };
  this.el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

  var about = {
    Version: "0.3",
    Author: "AppleProSchool, Adam Izgin",
    Created: "Fall 2018, Tuesday 5, November",
    Updated: "Tuesday 6, November",
  }
};
aps.prototype.css = function(property, value) {
  this.el.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style[property] = value;
  });
  return this;
};
```

and for example if I would do this:

```
(window.onload = function() {
    aps('.test').css({ background: '#0f0' });//That does not return anything. Why?
});
```

But when I do this:

```
(window.onload = function() {
    aps('.test').css('background', '#0f0');//It works.
});
```

And I do have a div with a background of red.

Any ideas why? Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function expects two arguments:

```
aps.prototype.css = function(property, value) {
```

So when you send it one argument (an object):

```
aps('.test').css({ background: '#0f0' })
```

the `property` argument contains `{background:'#0f0'}` which won't be extracted properly with:

```
element.style[property]
```

and the function can't find the information it needs for`value`, so that will be `undefined`.

But, when you send in two arguments:

```
aps('.test').css('background', '#0f0')
```

it works.

---

If you want to use the Object syntax, you'll need to update your function to expect just a single argument and the function will have to "unpack" the data it needs from that object. It would look like this:

```
aps.prototype.css = function(obj) {
  this.el.forEach(function(element) {
    // Use the first key name in the object and the first key value
    element.style[Object.keys(obj)[0]] = Object.values(obj)[0];
  });
  return this;
};
```

Comment: Yes, ok. But how can I make it like an object? I found it more efficient that way.

Comment: @codeWithMe To be clear, you didn't ask for a way to make it work with the object variant. You asked *Any ideas why?*. However, I have updated my answer to show how that could be done.

Comment: Thank you **very** much for this answer, I am so grateful!